# Passing a TextBox name parameter from MainWindow.xaml to button_click Function

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am making a form that uses Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog(); to provide a file selecting menu.

I want to use the same function to update a Textbox for the input file and a Textbox for the Output file.

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="515" Height="96" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TextBlock Text="Input File:"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
        <TextBox x:Name="InputFileBox" Width ="213" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextChanged="InputFileBox_TextChanged" Height="17" Margin="0,39,0,40"  />
        <Button Content="Browse" Width="47" Margin="0,39,0,40" RenderTransformOrigin="1.599,0.714" Click="Browse_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>


    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="515" Height="96" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TextBlock Text="Output File:"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
        <TextBox x:Name="OutputFileBox" Width ="213" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextChanged="OutputFileBox_TextChanged" Height="17" Margin="0,39,0,40"  />
        <Button Content="Browse2" Width="47" Margin="0,39,0,40" RenderTransformOrigin="1.599,0.714" Click="Browse_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

So I want to be able to send the "InputFileBox" or "OutputFileBox" with the "BrowseClick" so that I don't have to have a BrowseInputClick and a BrowseOutputClick function.

in the Browse_Click function I want to be able to do something like:

```
 private void Browse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create OpenFileDialog 
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();


        // Display OpenFileDialog by calling ShowDialog method 
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();


        // Get the selected file name and display in a TextBox 
        if (result == true)
        {
            // Open document 
            string filename = dlg.FileName;

            // I don't know what to put here: input/outputTextBoxName = filename
        }
```

thanks

Comment: you can create a usercontrol and reuse in both the places.

Comment: file name should be a property of the textbox not a private member. you should create a property and bind it into the text box

Comment: Also please look into MVVM before you use WPF, don't use code behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WPF you can set the tag property of a button.

Once you have that you can get the tag property in the click handler using

In the XAML add `Tag="input"` as one of the properties on the inputTextBox and `Tag="output"` to the outputTextBox (for example: `<TextBox x:Name="inputTextBox" Tag="input"/>`)

```
var tag = (sender as Button).Tag;
```

Then:

```
if (tag == 'input')
    inputTextBox.Text = filename;
else outputTextBox.Text = filename;
```

Comment: That works but is there no way to pass the TextBox by reference so that the handler doesn't need to know how many different TextBoxs might be sent.

Comment: You could use binding to bind the tag to the textbox you want to change